# (PHP) Getting null in a preg_match instead of getting a empty string

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, preg-match

I have the following code:

```
$pattern = '(([a-z]{2})/)?(([a-z]{3,})/)?(\d{4}+)(/(\d{2})(/(\d{2}))?)?';

preg_match('#^' . $pattern . '$#i', '2010/12/01', $match);

$match = Array (
    [0] => 2010/12/01
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 2010
    [6] => /12/01
    [7] => 12
    [8] => /01
    [9] => 01
)
```

The problem is that $match[1], $match[2], $match[3] and match[4] are `string(0)`, **is there any way to modify the `$pattern` in order to get `null` instead of `string(0)`?**

Comment: Which version of PHP are you targeting?

Comment: I was wondering is your source always like `YYYY/MM/DD`?

Comment: Why do you want it null and not ''. I dont think this is possible but we can help with a workaround.

Comment: The problem is that when I join it with another array, the string(0) parameters do not get replaced.

Comment: A quick workaround: `foreach( $match as &$item ) if( $item == '' ) $item = null;`

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible in PHP. The preg_match() function only deals with strings and *null* is an entirely other data type.

Converting this to what you want is simple though. In PHP 5.3 you can use an anonymous function with [array_walk()](http://php.net/array_walk) to iterate over the array and then update your values with a shortened [ternary operation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

```
array_walk($array, function(&$val) { $val = $val ?: null; });
```